# Strange roots `using numpy.roots`

Tags: numpy

Is there something wrong in the evaluation of the polinomial `(1-alpha*z)**9` using numpy? For
`alpha=3/sqrt(2)` my list of coefficients is given in the array

```
psi_t0 =  [1.0, -19.0919, 162.0, -801.859, 2551.5, -5412.55, 7654.5, -6958.99, 3690.56, -869.874]
```

According to numpy documentation, I have to invert this array in order to compute the zeros, i.e.

```
psi_t0 = psi_t0[::-1]
```

Thus giving

```
a = np.roots(psi_t0)
[0.62765842+0.06979364j 0.62765842-0.06979364j 0.52672941+0.14448097j  0.52672941-0.14448097j 0.42775926+0.13031547j 0.42775926-0.13031547j  0.36690056+0.07504044j 0.36690056-0.07504044j 0.34454214+0.j]
```

which is completely crap since the roots must be all equal to `sqrt(2)/3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you take the 9th power you'll find that you create a very "wide" zero, indeed, if you step eps away from the true zero and evaluate you'll get something of O(eps^9). In view of that numerical inaccuracies are all but expected.

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(4)
>>> print(C)
[-8.6987e+02  3.6906e+03 -6.9590e+03  7.6545e+03 -5.4125e+03  2.5515e+03
 -8.0186e+02  1.6200e+02 -1.9092e+01  1.0000e+00]
>>> np.roots(C)
array([0.4881+0.0062j, 0.4881-0.0062j, 0.4801+0.0154j, 0.4801-0.0154j,
       0.4681+0.0172j, 0.4681-0.0172j, 0.458 +0.011j , 0.458 -0.011j ,
       0.4541+0.j    ])
>>> np.polyval(C,_)
array([1.4622e-13+6.6475e-15j, 1.4622e-13-6.6475e-15j,
       1.2612e-13+1.5363e-14j, 1.2612e-13-1.5363e-14j,
       1.0270e-13+1.3600e-14j, 1.0270e-13-1.3600e-14j,
       1.1346e-13+9.7179e-15j, 1.1346e-13-9.7179e-15j,
       1.0936e-13+0.0000e+00j])
```

As you can see the roots numpy returns are "good" in that the polynomial evaluates to something pretty close to zero at these points.

Comment: I don't understand, your `print(C)` is using more significant numbers in each coefficient? I had substituted the values as you did and get "zeroes", but this does not solve the problem. Are you implying that one needs higher powers in the polynomial?

Comment: @user2820579 Nope, as I was trying to explain the high multiplicity of thet same root is the problem, because it makes the function very shallow around the root. This will throw off many general purpose root finders.

Comment: Ah ok. As a general question, for a polynomial with more or less random coefficients, this will not appear right? As you said, I just tested the problem in gp-pari and I encounter the same issue.

Comment: It shouldn't, no. Just be aware that high order has a couple of ways of biting you numerically, so if you can get away with low order this can make your life easier.