# numpy roots() returns false roots

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, linear-algebra

I'm trying to use numpy to find the roots of some polynomials, but I am getting some erroneous results:

```
>> poly = np.polynomial.Polynomial([4.383930e+00, 2.277144e+14, -7.008406e+25, -4.258004e+16])
>> roots = poly.roots()
>> roots
array([-1.64593692e+09, -1.91391398e-14,  3.26830022e-12])
>> poly(roots)
array([-3.74803539e+23, -7.99360578e-15, -1.89182003e-13])
```

What is up with the false root `-1.64593692e+09` which results in `-3.74803539e+23`? This is clearly not a root.

Is this the result of floating-point errors? or something else?..

And more importantly;

> **Is there a way to get around it?**

..perhaps something I can tweak, or a different function I can use?. Any help is much appreciated.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64288070/strange-roots-using-numpy-roots) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318988/numpy-throws-incorrect-roots) previous question which seemed to be related, but after reading them and the answers/comments I don't think that they are the same problem.

Comment: Your polynomial has coefficients with very different scales ranging on several decade. Computation will certainly be affected by float arithmetic errors.

Comment: Even more fun: if you type in `poly(-1.64593692e+09)` that *significantly* affects the result. That should tell you something about just how close that result really is, in relative terms.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, computing the roots of a polynomial is a classically ill-conditioned problem, meaning (roughly) that no matter what algorithm you use to solve it, small changes in the coefficients of many polynomials can lead to huge changes in their roots. That means we should be a little careful not to place an extraordinary amount of faith in root-finding results in general, and that perhaps that we shouldn't be too surprised when a root finder gives weird results. There's a pretty good example on Wikipedia, [Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial), that shows how things can go wrong.

In this instance, the coefficients of the polynomial of interest are of such different magnitudes that it's not surprising that the results seem poor. But consider this: if our original polynomial is `p()` and it has a root `x`, then `p(x) = 0`, but also `c*p(x) = 0` for any constant `c`. In other words, we can scale the coefficients without changing the roots, so happen if we normalized the polynomial by dividing by the coefficient of largest magnitude, 7e25?

- Original polynomial: `p(x) = 4.4 + 2.3e+14*x - 7.0e25*x**2 - 4.3e16*x**3`
- Scaled polynomial: `p(x) = 6.3e-26 + 3.2e-12*x - x**2 - 6.1e-10*x**3`

So for this polynomial, the largest coefficient ~7e25 is so huge that the smallest coefficient ~4.4 is essentially negligible. That should give us a hint that what counts as zero in a root finding iteration isn't what we would normally consider "small."

The short answer is that the root calculated by NumPy isn't perfect, but it is an estimate of an actual root. Here's some code to convince us.

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> coefs = np.array([4.383930e+00, 2.277144e+14, -7.008406e+25, -4.258004e+16])
>>> coefs_normed = coefs / np.abs(coefs).max()
>>> coefs_normed
array([ 6.25524549e-26,  3.24916108e-12, -1.00000000e+00, -6.07556697e-10])

>>> poly = np.polynomial.Polynomial(coefs)
>>> roots = poly.roots()
>>> roots
array([-1.64593692e+09, -1.91391398e-14,  3.26830022e-12])
>>> poly(roots)
array([-3.74803539e+23,  8.43769499e-14, -1.89182003e-13])

>>> poly_normed = np.polynomial.Polynomial(coefs_normed)
>>> roots_normed = poly_normed.roots()
>>> roots_normed
array([-1.64593692e+09, -1.91391398e-14,  3.26830022e-12])
>>> poly_normed(roots_normed)
array([-5.34791419e-03,  1.20534089e-39, -2.11221641e-39])
```

Now, `-5e-03` is not very close to machine epsilon, but that should convince us that maybe the calculated root isn't quite as bad as it seemed at first.

A final point: the `np.polynomial.Polynomial` class has `domain` and `window` arguments that determine how it does its computations. Since polynomials get absolutely huge as the domain tends to +infinity or -infinity, it's unrealistic to expect accurate calculations for a value around 10^9.

Comment: Good point, thx, I like your point about scaling the polynomial not changing the roots.. Using the window arg doesn't help..

Answer (score 1):

The root appears real:

```
x = np.linspace(-2e9, 1000, 10000)
plt.plot(x, poly(x))
```

[image]

The problem is that the scale of the data is very large. -3e23 is tiny compared to say 6e43. The discrepancy is caused by roundoff error. Third order polynomials have an analytical solution, but it's not going to be numerically stable when your domain is on the order of 1e9.

You can try to use the `domain` and `window` parameters to attempt to introduce some numerical stability. For example, a common choice of domain is something that envelops your entire dataset. You would have to adjust the coefficients to compenstate, since those values are usually used for fitting data.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, I didn't notice how far outside my fitted dataset the root actually is, I guess the solution is just to filter roots by whether they are in a reasonable range of my actual data, or many orders of magnitude outside.